# Half Bridge motor braking

Tags: motor, braking

I have a motor that only runs in one direction.  I currently use a fqp30n06L logic level MOSFET to control the motor.  Once the MOSFET gate is grounded, the motor does stop but it freewheels.  I also have on hand some p channel MOSFETS, FQP27P06.  The motor is a 12v motor.  Is it possible to use two of the N channel logic MOSFETS or a combination of the N channel and P channel that i have on hand to construct a circuit that also has braking in an H bridge layout?  If so, would anyone be willing to supply a schematic using the two for me to learn by?

Comment: You need to reverse torque for braking. That means reversing current flow and that means you need a standard (full) H bridge. A half bridge will only allow current be reversed if the input voltage is less than the back EMF voltage (e.g. by  shorting the motor's terminals.)

Comment: Is there an h-bridge design that only takes one input?  I only have a signal that tells the motor to go (high) and stop (low) on the 5v gate.

Comment: That won't work as you had to stop braking as soon the motor is at still. You need to monitor the speed, or the reverse torque will make it accelerate in the reverse direction.